# Is maglietta a T-shirt, a shirt or a sweater?

Tags: word-meaning

In English, a T-shirt is a thin, short-sleeved shirt with no collar and no buttons. [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/maglietta) says that T-shirt is "maglietta" or "t-shirt" (anglicism) in Italian. However, I suspect that the former has not a 1-1 relationship with the English term. Is that right?

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maglietta/) says that "maglietta" means "capo d’abbigliamento estivo di leggera maglia di cotone, con o senza maniche, generalm. lungo fino alla vita" (= light piece of clothing for the summer, made of cotton, with or without sleeves, generally long until the waist). There is no explicit reference to short sleeves and lack of collar and buttons. Although I cannot understand how a piece of clothing for the summer could be long-sleeved, a search on Google Images for "maglietta" has surprised me and brought me a sporty shirt and a sweater:

- http://www.rockexperience.it/it/home/1414-maglietta-a-maniche-lunghe-oxygen-uomo-viola.html
- https://www.atipicishop.com/en/tees/1000016213-maglietta-maniche-lunghe-octopus-logo-l-s-black.html.

Are those really "maglietta"s?

Comment: No, they are _magliette_. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic word here is *maglia*, which is any “Indumento esterno di maglia di lana o di cotone, di forma e colori varî, che ricopre la parte superiore del corpo” ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maglia1/)): an outer garment in wool or cotton, of various shapes and colours, covering the upper part of the body.

Then, light *maglie*, generally made of cotton, are called *magliette*, but there is no precise, complete definition. By the same token, an heavy *maglia*, especially a woollen one, is often called a *maglione*.

Answer (score 4):

The "magliette" in your Google links are "magliette con le maniche lunghe", that is "long sleeved T-Shirt".

To make it simple, "maglietta" = T-Shirt. In the last 20 years, the "T-Shirt" noun has become very popular here in Italy.

This said, there could be different meanings of "maglietta" in different regions.

Somehow, "maglietta" is also "small maglia". In an alpine region, it could refer to a warmer garment compared to a "sicilian maglietta". Italian is always a bit subjective, and it depends a lot on the region where it is spoken.

To wrap up, I suggest to stick to "Maglietta=T-Shirt", but be ready to meet some exceptions.